# Python pandas dataframe with daily data - keep first and last rows per month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
print(dataframe1.head(30))
                    Date   Close* month_initial  month day  year
date_final                                                      
2022-09-23  Sep 23, 2022  3693.23           Sep    9.0  23  2022
2022-09-22  Sep 22, 2022  3757.99           Sep    9.0  22  2022
2022-09-21  Sep 21, 2022  3789.93           Sep    9.0  21  2022
2022-09-20  Sep 20, 2022  3855.93           Sep    9.0  20  2022
2022-09-19  Sep 19, 2022  3899.89           Sep    9.0  19  2022
2022-09-16  Sep 16, 2022  3873.33           Sep    9.0  16  2022
2022-09-15  Sep 15, 2022  3901.35           Sep    9.0  15  2022
2022-09-14  Sep 14, 2022  3946.01           Sep    9.0  14  2022
2022-09-13  Sep 13, 2022  3932.69           Sep    9.0  13  2022
2022-09-12  Sep 12, 2022  4110.41           Sep    9.0  12  2022
2022-09-09  Sep 09, 2022  4067.36           Sep    9.0  09  2022
2022-09-08  Sep 08, 2022  4006.18           Sep    9.0  08  2022
2022-09-07  Sep 07, 2022  3979.87           Sep    9.0  07  2022
2022-09-06  Sep 06, 2022  3908.19           Sep    9.0  06  2022
2022-09-02  Sep 02, 2022  3924.26           Sep    9.0  02  2022
2022-09-01  Sep 01, 2022  3966.85           Sep    9.0  01  2022
2022-08-31  Aug 31, 2022  3955.00           Aug    8.0  31  2022
2022-08-30  Aug 30, 2022  3986.16           Aug    8.0  30  2022
2022-08-29  Aug 29, 2022  4030.61           Aug    8.0  29  2022
2022-08-26  Aug 26, 2022  4057.66           Aug    8.0  26  2022
2022-08-25  Aug 25, 2022  4199.12           Aug    8.0  25  2022
2022-08-24  Aug 24, 2022  4140.77           Aug    8.0  24  2022
2022-08-23  Aug 23, 2022  4128.73           Aug    8.0  23  2022
2022-08-22  Aug 22, 2022  4137.99           Aug    8.0  22  2022
2022-08-19  Aug 19, 2022  4228.48           Aug    8.0  19  2022
2022-08-18  Aug 18, 2022  4283.74           Aug    8.0  18  2022
2022-08-17  Aug 17, 2022  4274.04           Aug    8.0  17  2022
2022-08-16  Aug 16, 2022  4305.20           Aug    8.0  16  2022
2022-08-15  Aug 15, 2022  4297.14           Aug    8.0  15  2022
2022-08-12  Aug 12, 2022  4280.15           Aug    8.0  12  2022
```

I want to keep the first and the last row per month. How can I do that? I tried using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe1.set_index("date_final", inplace=True)
resultDf = dataframe1.groupby([dataframe1.index.year, dataframe1.index.month]).agg(["first", "last"])
resultDf.index.rename(["year", "month"], inplace=True)
resultDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
resultDf
```

but I don't get the results I want.

Comment: perhaps you should sort by `date_final` at the very beginning

Comment: If I sort I get `   year month          Date               Close*  ... month   day       year      
                      first          last  first  ...  last first last first  last
0  1949     8  Aug 08, 1949  Aug 31, 1949  15.51  ...   8.0    08   31  1949  1949
1  1949     9  Sep 01, 1949  Sep 30, 1949  15.31  ...   9.0    01   30  1949  1949
2  1949    10  Oct 03, 1949  Oct 31, 1949  15.60  ...  10.0    03   31  1949  1949` which has many columns with the same names and I don't know how to handle this dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` groupby operations don't sort each group prior to aggregation, which is why `'first'` and `'last'` are not selecting the correct rows for you.

Additionally, you can use `.resample('M')` instead of a groupby on year & month.

```py
out = (
    df.set_index(df.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')) # copying in the data, I lost the datetime index
    .sort_index()  # sort ensures first and last work as expected
    .resample('M') # resample for a shorthand year/month grouping
    .agg(['first', 'last'])
)

print(out)
                    Date                 Close*          month_initial      month        day       year      
                   first          last    first     last         first last first last first last first  last
date_final                                                                                                   
2022-08-31  Aug 12, 2022  Aug 31, 2022  4280.15  3955.00           Aug  Aug   8.0  8.0    12   31  2022  2022
2022-09-30  Sep 01, 2022  Sep 23, 2022  3966.85  3693.23           Sep  Sep   9.0  9.0     1   23  2022  2022
```

This output doesn't have the most usable format, so we can use a quick `.stack` to remedy it:

```py
out = out.stack()

print(out)
                          Date   Close* month_initial  month  day  year
date_final                                                             
2022-08-31 first  Aug 12, 2022  4280.15           Aug    8.0   12  2022
           last   Aug 31, 2022  3955.00           Aug    8.0   31  2022
2022-09-30 first  Sep 01, 2022  3966.85           Sep    9.0    1  2022
           last   Sep 23, 2022  3693.23           Sep    9.0   23  2022
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`is_month_start`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.is_month_start.html)  and [`is_month_end`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.is_month_end.html#pandas.Series.dt.is_month_end) functions

In your case, the following should work

```
dataframe1.set_index("date_final", inplace=True) 
dataframe1 = dataframe1[dataframe1.index.is_month_start | dataframe1.index.is_month_end]
```